# Invalid comparison error when converting datatime data type

Tags: python, datetime

Getting the error "Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date"

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df[['starttime']
```

2019-06-29 12:00:20 AM

```
df['starttime_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])

df['starttime_datetime']
```

2019-06-29 00:00:20

```
df = df[df['starttime_datetime']<date(2019, 6, 30)]
```

"Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date"

Comment: It's not easy to make your example run, too many missing pieces. have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Aside for that it looks like you should probably just do the same date transform on date() before comparing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas datetime comparison can't be used with the `datetime` module.

I suggest you to just use string comparison:

```
df = df[df['starttime_datetime'] < '2019-06-30']
```